# Querying data in ravendb

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

Inside ravendb I have Properties documents. Each document has besides other properties UniqueCode. How can I query document for specific document inside ravendb management studio.

I tried inside Query (top level link) using

```
from d in docs.Properties
where d.UniqueCode == 1234
select d;
```

But I'm getting `No results found`

Metadata for each property document is

```
{
    "Raven-Entity-Name": "Properties",
    "Raven-Clr-Type": "MyProject.Test.Data.Domain.Model.Property, MyProject.Test.Data"
}
```

Comment: What purpose does "properties" serve?

Comment: just an entity name (document in this case). Can be Users or anything else from domain model.

Comment: It sounds like your domain is designed poorly. You shouldn't have a catch all object/collection.

Comment: I am hoping by "Can be Users or anything else.." you mean you want to do a similar query to this for other models, and not that you're using a Properties model to store unrelated entities in a generic way (as Phill interprets)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query UI in RavenDb Management Studio uses [Lucene syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html), and operates on [indexes](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/csharp/indexes/what-are-indexes).

You need to first define an index that includes any fields you want to be able to search on:

```
from p in docs.Properties
select new {
    p.UniqueCode
}
```

Now you can use lucene syntax to actually query this:

```
UniqueCode: 1234
```

---

Using the RavenDb sample, I will define a similar query:

[image: ProductReorderLevel query]

and then can find all products matching a specific value:

[image]